# What is the role of the this variable when it comes to function currying using the .bind()?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, bind, currying

I came across to the following JS code (ES5)
and I don't really I understand what is the meaning of the this variable.

```
function multiply(a,b){
  return a * b;
}

var multipleByThree = multiply.bind(this,3);

multipleByThree(10) // outputs 30
```

I do understand that the bind copies the multiply function and that 'a' parameter of it, will have the value 3. But what is the purpose of the this variable?

Can you help me out please?

Comment: In this particular case: nothing, since `multiply` doesn't use `this` in any way.

Comment: this is a option in the function so you can pass any context to the call which function can use...

Comment: Without it I get a NaN result. Why is the 'this' variable necessary?

Comment: It would have been better to pass `null` instead of the meaningless `this`. (No, you can't just omit it).

Comment: This indicates that you are you're misusing  the `bind` method for currying. Please use closures instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` variable that you are providing to `.bind()` is the context. In your case, `this` refers to the global object space.

Here's an example of how this works:

```js
var message = 'within global context';
function multiply(a,b){
  console.log(this.message);
  return a * b;
}

var someOtherContext = {
  message: 'within some other context'
};

var multipleByThree = multiply.bind(this,3);
var multipleByThreeOtherContext = multiply.bind(someOtherContext, 3);

console.log(multipleByThree(10))
console.log(multipleByThreeOtherContext(10))
```

By changing the context that multiply executed within, we can change what variables it references.

Comment: *"`this` refers to the global object space"* … ***assuming*** this code is used in a global context.

Comment: ...or isn't in strict mode.

Comment: @deceze is it possible for you to edit the answer to add on to it, or I can edit (just want to make sure everyone with good answers/suggestions gets some stackoverflow rep/karma out of it)

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `bind` must be the `thisArg`:

> ```
> fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
> ```
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

That is, whatever the keyword `this` *inside* `multiply` will refer to. Since `multiply` doesn't use `this` at all, it's irrelevant what it refers to. You must still pass *something* as the first argument to `bind`, so likely the developer simply chose `this` (whatever that refers to in this code is unknown to us), but they could just as well have used `false`, `null` or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript `this` is some kind of "reserved keyword" which refers to current object of the scope.

If `this` used outside of any object - it refers to `window` object.
Inside eventhandlers `this` refers to the DOM object which raised an event.

`bind` function provide possibility to define which object `this` will refer inside bound function.

For example if you using `this` inside function

```
const calculate = function (price, amount) {
    return (price * amount) - this.discount;
};
```

You can bound a function with predefined `this`

```
const calculateWithDiscount = calculate.bind({ discount: 100 });

const total = calculateWithDiscount(1000, 2); // return 1900
```

When you bound function which doesn't use `this` object, you can easily pass `null` there, which clearly "tell" other developers your intents about using `this` in the function.

```
const add = function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
};
const add5 = add.bind(null, 5);

const result = add5(19); // return 24
```

[bind Method (Function) (JavaScript)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/bind-method-function-javascript)

Comment: Bad example, fat arrow functions don't have a `this` of their own. You cannot modify or bind `this` on a fat arrow function.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, you can do currying without relying upon `Function.prototype.bind`

Once you stop relying upon `this` in JavaScript, your programs can start looking like beautiful expressions

```js
const curry = f => x => y =>
  f (x,y)
  
const mult = (x,y) =>
  x * y

const multByThree =
  curry (mult) (3)
  
console.log (multByThree (10)) // 30
```

---

For a more generic `curry` implementation that works on functions of varying arity

```
const curry = (f, n = f.length, xs = []) =>
  n === 0
    ? f (...xs)
    : x => curry (f, n - 1, xs.concat ([x]))
```

If you want to bellyache about the exposed private API, hide it away with a loop – either way, `this` is not required to write functional programs in JavaScript

```
const loop = f =>
  {
    const recur = (...values) =>
      f (recur, ...values)
    return f (recur)
  }

const curry = f =>
  loop ((recur, n = f.length, xs = []) =>
    n === 0
      ? f (...xs)
      : x => recur (n - 1, xs.concat ([x])))
```

Answer (score 0):

it fixes 3 as the first argument, the arguments of the new function will be preceded by 3

```js
function multiply(a,b){
  console.log(a, b);
  console.log(arguments)
  return a * b;
}

var multipleByThree = multiply.bind(console.log(this),3);

console.log(multipleByThree(10)) // outputs 30
console.log(multipleByThree(10, 15)) // outputs 30
```

passing **this** would provide a copy of this(i.e the global object) with the preceded arguments list

For more information check out the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: `this` here does not refer to `multiply`. Nobody knows that `this` refers to here (though probably `window`).

Answer (score 0):

In the context of Currying the this object in the code presented has no purpose other than as a *placeholder*. You could replace this with the string "cats" if you wanted and still get the same result. It is simply there to occupy the first argument position and I think it is very misleading to use it in the context of 
either currying or partial application when using bind. It is better to replace it with the null keyword.

In the case of this example it will pass in the global object and the rest of the code will simply ignore that value since the keyword 'this' is not present *within* the multiply function itself.

MDN shows a use case, visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
and scroll to the section headed Partially applied functions.

ES6 (aka es2015) has improved on the way this code is written by using arrow functions and the code can now be reduced to the following

```
const multiply = a => b => a * b

const multiplyByThree = multiply(3)

const result = multiplyByThree(10)
console.log(result)
// => 30
```